# SharePoint 2010 log4net EventReceiver not work

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, logging

I'm developing one SharePoint Farm Solution with SharePoint 2010 Foundation. I've used log4net for logging.

I configured my log4net inside assembly info using:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @"C:\Log\log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

And I get one instance of logger object using:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

My log4net.config file have the following xml:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:\Log\Log.log" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
            <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:\Log\Log.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="1024KB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %M - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>

</log4net>
```

Now, the problem is this: when I try to deploy my application, log4net work fine, but after deployment, when I execute the action:

```
log.Info("MyInfo");
```

There is no text in the file.

Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Just a thought, why not log to the ULS logs in code? Reference: https://blog.mastykarz.nl/logging-uls-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, but this is a requirement of my client...

Comment: This is more of a StackOverflow question. Ask it there, although I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898218/log4net-not-working

Comment: Hi Mike, I configured log4net but it not work (please see my post). If I create one Console application log4net work. I think that the problem is other...